# Как зашифровать swap в Linux?

Tags: linux, криптография, swap

Установил `cryptsetup libpam-mount`. Отключил файл подкачки. Написал

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda5 bs=1M
```

потом написал

```
 cryptoswap /dev/sda5 /dev/urandom cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256,size=256,hash=sha256,swap
```

и терминал выдаёт:

```
cryptoswap: command not found
```

Comment: так cryptoswap в пути нет наверное